# Weird issue with media player and async playing aacp/shoutcast stream on android

Tags: java, android, aac

I'm trying to build a custom player for a radio station, and they want to move from mpeg to aac to lower the bitrate (mostly for mobile users) however when i started the project i was testing it against the mpeg stream, When i change it to the new aac stream my player seems to lock for a period of time, then the UI thread is killed by android while the player is attempting to load the stream in the background. I do get some initial errors about it being unable to play, but maybe 30 seconds after the app is killed i get an orphaned async player re-spawning in the background with it's sticky notification and the stream starts playing?

the logcat output shows these lines around when it crashes
I/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=3: reacting to signal 
I/dalvikvm﹕ Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x000008eb (code=0), thread 32258

I see the sticky for the orphaned async task and it's playing audio when i click it (to regain audio focus) but the main app/ui thread is obviously completely reset

The code that spawns the async task is as follows:

```
private class PlayAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {
   private String url_to_play = "";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        textView_info.setText("Buffering...");

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {

        url_to_play = params[0];
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("url", url_to_play);
        Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MusicService.class);
        i.putExtras(b);

        try {
            stopService(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MusicService.class));
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            //
        }
        startService(i);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        isMuted = isMuted();
        if (isMuted) {
            textView_info.setText("Playing Muted!");
        } else
            textView_info.setText("Playing");
        isBuffering = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {

    }

    protected void onError(MusicService mp, int what, int extra) {
        // The MediaPlayer has moved to the Error state, must be reset!
        button_stop.performClick();
    }
}
```